# Reading raw section with ConfigParser

Tags: python

I'm attempting to use the [ConfigParser](http://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html) module to process a file that is **almost** completely in the .ini format.  I want to know if it's possible to read a section 'raw' where I just get the full text inside the section.  If not possible, I'd like to know if there is another 'standard-ish' approach (with a built-in module(s)) to deal with this type of file, possibly including [shlex](http://docs.python.org/2/library/shlex.html#module-shlex) or something similar in the standard library.

I've looked through the source of [ConfigParser](http://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html), and it doesn't look like the text is stored 'raw' anywhere so I'm guessing it's not possible.

I think an example of the file I'm trying to parse will help.  I'd like to have a file with 3 sections:

```
[load]
files=a,b,c

[process]
<raw python code>

[export]
files=x,y,z
```

The idea is that the load/export sections are the exact format/behavior assumed by the ConfigParser module.  However, the `process` section needs to be read as raw Python code.  Users will put raw code in here that needs to be executed a number of times based on data loaded from files in the `load` section.

This isn't the most complicated format, so I could easily write my own parser.  I also have the ability to change the format of the file to not be .ini style if needed.  I just want to provide users with the ability to have multiple sections and a 'raw' Python code section.  Maybe ConfigParser is the wrong approach entirely.

I'd prefer to not write my own parser for this just because it seems so similar to existing formats.  However, I could easily choose another 'standard' format if it's better suited.  I just don't know of other such formats.

Comment: Note that `[export]` and `files=x,y,z` are both valid expressions in Python, so how would you determine the end of the `[process]` section? I think the answer here is that `ConfigParser` isn't going to be suitable, unfortunately, unless there are some constraints you can place on the `<raw python code>`.

Comment: @Aya I think you're right.  I believe I can make the assumption that `[export]` is actually the end of the `[process]` section.  However, it's still a bit of a hack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you're prepared to assume that `[process]` always precedes `[export]`, and that `[export]` will always mark the end of the Python code, then you could pre-process the ini file to strip out that section before passing it to the `ConfigParser` with something like this...

```
from ConfigParser import RawConfigParser
from StringIO import StringIO

START_PROCESS_TOKEN = '[process]'
END_PROCESS_TOKEN = '[export]'

def hacky_parse(stream):
    state = 0
    ini_io = StringIO()
    python_io = StringIO()
    for line in stream.readlines():
        if state == 0:
            if line.strip() == START_PROCESS_TOKEN:
                state = 1
                continue
            ini_io.write(line)
        elif state == 1:
            if line.strip() == END_PROCESS_TOKEN:
                ini_io.write(line)
                state = 2
                continue
            python_io.write(line)
        else:
            ini_io.write(line)

    ini_io.seek(0)
    python_io.seek(0)

    config_parser = RawConfigParser()
    config_parser.readfp(ini_io)

    python_code = python_io.getvalue()

    return config_parser, python_code


cfg = """
[load]
files=a,b,c

[process]
while 1:
    do_stuff()

[export]
files=x,y,z
"""

my_stream = StringIO(cfg)
config_parser, process_code = hacky_parse(my_stream)
print 'The value of "files" in section "load" is...'
print config_parser.get('load', 'files')
print
print 'The raw Python code is...'
print process_code
```

...which yields...

```
The value of "files" in section "load" is...
a,b,c

The raw Python code is...
while 1:
    do_stuff()
```

...obviously, substituting `my_stream` for a real file-object with something like...

```
my_stream = open('config.ini', 'r')
```

**Update**

Well, there's more potential for breakage with your code, e.g., if the line `[load]` appears in the Python code.

I just thought of another option. If you made the config file look like an RFC822 message...

```
Load-Files: a,b,c
Export-Files: x,y,z

# Python code starts here
while 1:
    do_stuff()
```

...you could parse it quite simply like this...

```
import email

cfg = \
"""Load-Files: a,b,c
Export-Files: x,y,z

# Python code starts here
while 1:
    do_stuff()
"""

msg = email.message_from_string(cfg)
print msg.items()
print
print msg.get_payload()
```

..which yields...

```
[('Load-Files', 'a,b,c'), ('Export-Files', 'x,y,z')]

# Python code starts here
while 1:
    do_stuff()
```

I mean, you don't have to use a strict RFC822 format, but the advantage of putting the Python code at the end of the config file is that there's no chance that anything in the code could conflict with the format you use for the remainder of the file.

Comment: That solution will definitely work.  I actually came up with [this](https://gist.github.com/durden/5513296).  I think yours could be a bit better performance wise because you do not read the `[process]` section twice.  However, performance is not a big issue here and can't really tell anything for sure without profiling.  Are there any other differences in the solutions that are notable?

Comment: I like the idea of using the RFC822 format.  It feels a little odd to `import email` to parse a file non-email file, but it sure makes parsing easier.

Comment: @durden2.0 Well, you can also use the [`rfc822`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/rfc822.html) module, but it's deprecated.